# Find files and rename and move to another directory

Tags: command-line, find, mv

When I run the command

```
find dir_1 -type f -name 'f*'
```

I found 2 files there "file_11" and "file_22".
Now I want to move those files to another directory "dir_2" using -exec with the "find" command.
So I use this command.

```
find dir_1 -type f -name 'f*' -exec mv {} ../dir2 \;
```

This command works.

Now, there are also some ".txt" files in the directory "dir_1". I want to move these text files to "dir2" and also rename these files. so I use this command,

```
find dir_1 -type f -name '*.txt' -exec mv {} ../dir2/new_{} \;
```

But I am getting the error,

```
mv: cannot move 'dir_1/file1.txt' to '../dir2/new_dir_1/file1.txt': No such file or directory
mv: cannot move 'dir_1/file2.txt' to '../dir2/new_dir_1/file2.txt': No such file or directory
```

Can anyone help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
find dir_1 -type f -name '*.txt' -exec \
    sh -c 'echo mv "$1" "/path/to/dir_2/new_${1##*/}"' sh_mv {} \;
```

the syntax *`${parameter##word}`* is the [shell parameter expansion.](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) and cuts-up-to-last-prefix specified by ***word*** from its given ***paramter***; here it strips the *path* part from the filename. so `./dir_1/sub_directory/file1.txt` becomes just `file1.txt` and later added `new_` to the filename.

the `sh -c '...'` construct is known as inline shell (here `sh` shell) and we open it in order to provide/build necessary parameters for the `mv` command to move &rename and using its parameter-expansion feature for that.

with `sh -c '...' sh_mv {}`, it's accepting two arguments, one is `sh_mv` (used as a label for the inline shell we open (parameter `$0`)); the `{}` argument will be the substitution of the fileName found by `find` command and will pass as next argument (parameter `$1`).

**note**: remove `echo` to perform actual mv which we used for dry-run to test.